# How to map by joining 2 different repeating nodes into a 1 repeating node using BizTalk mapper

Tags: join, mapping, nodes, biztalk, repeat

The issue is I need to loop over a repeating node but pull info also from a sibling repeating node which matches based on LineId.  If this were a database, I would equate each repeating node as a table and want to out put the join of the two tables based on matching ids.

I started out by looping on Root/Shipments/Shipment/Containers/Container to Document/Header/Detail and that seemed to work, since I wanted to create 1 record for every Container from the source as 1 Detail record in the destination. But when I mapped the fields from Root/Shipments/Shipment/Details/Detail, I only got the data from the first record mapped instead of the record with the matching LineId. I then tried adding Root/Shipments/Shipment/Details/Detail to the loop and conditionally suppress Document/Detail where LineId didn't match between the nodes but that didn't work. So, I tried adding a second loop on Detail with same suppress condition and that didn't work either. Then I thought I would try using XSLT Template to "lookup" the data in Root/Shipments/Shipment/Details/Detail based on LineId as an input, but it never returned any data (it was always empty). Also, to fetch each field separately at the field level I would need to search X times, 1 for each field I needed to map instead of 1 time per record, so that seemed inefficient also.

My XSLT knowledge is limited.  If possible, I would prefer to use Mapping with script functoids rather than pure XSLT.  Performance will be an issue too since the # of files I need to do is very high on this project.  The examples I give below are a VERY cut down version of what I need to do with dozens more fields and the source file has several more layers to the hierarchy.

What is the best way to achieve what I need to do?

Source File:

```
<Root>
  <Shipments>
    <Shipment>
      <ShipId>1</ShipId>
      <Details>
        <Detail>
          <LineId>1</LineId>
          <RequestedQty>10</RequestedQty>
          <Sku>347</Sku>
          <Status>C</Status>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <LineId>2</LineId>
          <RequestedQty>5</RequestedQty>
          <Sku>125</Sku>
          <Status>P</Status>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <LineId>3</LineId>
          <RequestedQty>8</RequestedQty>
          <Sku>337</Sku>
          <Status>O</Status>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
          <LineId>4</LineId>
          <RequestedQty>12</RequestedQty>
          <Sku>7438</Sku>
          <Status>C</Status>
        </Detail>
      </Details>
      <Containers>
        <Container>
          <ContainerId>1</ContainerId>
          <Details>
            <Detail>
              <LineId>1</LineId>
              <Lot>103</Lot>
              <ShipQty>10</ShipQty>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
              <LineId>2</LineId>
              <Lot>102</Lot>
              <ShipQty>3</ShipQty>
            </Detail>
          </Details>
          <TrackingNUmber>Z934793498923984</TrackingNUmber>
        </Container>
        <Container>
          <ContainerId>2</ContainerId>
          <Details>
            <Detail>
              <LineId>4</LineId>
              <Lot>101</Lot>
              <ShipQty>10</ShipQty>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
              <LineId>4</LineId>
              <Lot>105</Lot>
              <ShipQty>2</ShipQty>
            </Detail>
          </Detail>
        </Details>
        <TrackingNUmber>Z531365161663161</TrackingNUmber>
      </Container>
    </Containers>
  </Shipment>
</Shipments>
</Root>
```

Into:

```
<Document>
  <Header>
    <ShipId>1</ShipId>
    <Detail>
      <ContainerId>1</ContainerId>
      <LineId>1</LineId>
      <Lot>103</Lot>
      <ShipQty>10</ShipQty>
      <RequestedQty>10</RequestedQty>
      <Sku>347</Sku>
      <Status>C</Status>
      <TrackingNUmber>Z934793498923984</TrackingNUmber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <ContainerId>1</ContainerId>
      <LineId>2</LineId>
      <Lot>102</Lot>
      <ShipQty>3</ShipQty>
      <RequestedQty>5</RequestedQty>
      <Sku>125</Sku>
      <Status>P</Status>
      <TrackingNUmber>Z934793498923984</TrackingNUmber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <ContainerId>2</ContainerId>
      <LineId>4</LineId>
      <Lot>101</Lot>
      <ShipQty>10</ShipQty>      
      <RequestedQty>12</RequestedQty>
      <Sku>7438</Sku>
      <Status>C</Status>
      <TrackingNUmber>Z531365161663161</TrackingNUmber>
    </Detail>
    <Detail>
      <ContainerId>2</ContainerId>
      <LineId>4</LineId>
      <Lot>105</Lot>
      <ShipQty>2</ShipQty>      
      <RequestedQty>12</RequestedQty>
      <Sku>7438</Sku>
      <Status>C</Status>
      <TrackingNUmber>Z531365161663161</TrackingNUmber>
    </Detail>
  </Header>
</Document>
```

Comment: **HOLD ON!**  To clarify, you need to merge the Detail records by LindId?

Comment: Yes by LineId.  I want to "join" the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it is the Best solution, but I have something that might get you going. The idea is to create the Detail-element in the target document using a scripting functoid.

Given that you have a lot of elements, I would suggest the following to get the names right:

1. Create a direct link with all elements you want to appear in the target Detail-element.
   [image: Direct links to get the names right]
2. "Validate Map" to get the xslt. Copy the Detail-element and its content.
3. Remove all direct links to the Detail element.
4. Add a looping functoid between source Container/Details/Detail and target Detail.
5. Add a scripting functoid, connect it to target Detail. Select Inline XSLT and paste the code you copied in step 2.
6. Test the map, to verify that most of it works (the Shipment/Details/Detail will still be wrong though)
7. Modify the xslt in the scripting functoid. You want a variable to point the the Shipment/Details/Detail element corresponding to your current line.

**Set variable based on current LineId:**

```
<xsl:variable name="CurrentShipmentDetail" select="../../../../Details/Detail[LineId=current()/LineId]"/>
```

8. Modify the elements so you select from the variable

**Before:**

```
<RequestedQty>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../../../Details/Detail/RequestedQty/text()" />
</RequestedQty>
```

**After:**

```
<RequestedQty>
    <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentShipmentDetail/RequestedQty/text()" />
</RequestedQty>
```

**The complete map:**

[image]

**And the complete xslt code:**

```
<Detail>
  <ContainerId>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../ContainerId/text()" />
  </ContainerId>
  <LineId>
    <xsl:value-of select="LineId/text()" />
  </LineId>
  <Lot>
    <xsl:value-of select="Lot/text()" />
  </Lot>
  <ShipQty>
    <xsl:value-of select="ShipQty/text()" />
  </ShipQty>

  <xsl:variable name="CurrentShipmentDetail" select="../../../../Details/Detail[LineId=current()/LineId]"/>
  <RequestedQty>
    <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentShipmentDetail/RequestedQty/text()" />
  </RequestedQty>
  <Sku>
    <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentShipmentDetail/Sku/text()" />
  </Sku>
  <Status>
    <xsl:value-of select="$CurrentShipmentDetail/Status/text()" />
  </Status>
  <TrackingNUmber>
    <xsl:value-of select="../../TrackingNUmber/text()" />
  </TrackingNUmber>
</Detail>
```

Comment: That looks like it may actually work.  I guess I'll need to get a better handle on XSLT.  I like that you used the GUI to create the initial script.  Your method gave me an idea.  Could I write one script to lookup the detail record and save it to a variable, then use other scripts for each field which will extract the field I want using the variable saved from the first script?  This way I can still use the GUI on the Container and link those directly still without resorting to XSLT for the data from Container.

Comment: My "idea" doesn't work.  You can't create XSLT Script without tying it to a node, and once you do, mapper will not allow you to link fields to that node or any of it's child's.  To bad you can't inject XSLT scripts without linking it to a destination node. David's suggestion works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Looping and the Equal Functoid.

Connect Shipment/Detail to Looping Functoid, then connect Container/Detail to that same Looping Functoid.

Then connect Shipment//LineId and Container//LindId to an Equal Functoid then connect the Equal Functoid to the targed Detail.

You'll see how the Mapper builds the loops and conditions in the xsl.  You can adjust from there.

Comment: This basically created a Detail in the destination for each Container node and Shipment/Detail node from source.  It didn't merge the data into the same destination Detail with only its data.   It was a good start though.
  <Detail>
   <ContainerId>2</ContainerId>
   <LineId>4</LineId>
   <Lot>101</Lot>
   <ShipQty>10</ShipQty>
   <TrackingNumber>Z531365161663161</TrackingNumber>
  </Detail>
  <Detail>
   <ContainerId>1</ContainerId>
   <RequestedQty>10</RequestedQty>
   <Sku>347</Sku>
   <Status>C</Status>
   <TrackingNumber>Z934793498923984</TrackingNumber>
  </Detail>

Comment: Then try linking Lot and ShipQty through the Looping Functoid instead of the parent Detail.

Comment: That was even worse.  I would get each row in Shipment/Details/Detail without the data in Container/Details/Detail,. Then a  row for each Container/Details/Detail for each individual field.  Basically 4 rows with just Lot and 4 rows with just ShipQty.